# Getting templated template function declaration correct

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl, variadic-templates

I've got a problem like this I am trying to make compile:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

struct Test
{
    template <template <typename...> class Container, typename T, typename... Args>
    void SetData(const Container<T, Args...>& data)
    {
        // compiles for vector but not array
        // 'void Test::SetData(const Container<T,Args...> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const Container<T,Args...> &' from 'std::array<float,3>' 

    }
};


int main()
{
    Test test;
    std::vector<int> vector{ 1,2,3 };
    std::array<float, 3> arr{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};

    test.SetData(vector);
    test.SetData(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Essentially I need a function signature that can accept any arbitary STL container (more specifically `std::vector` and `std::array`) and I need the type `T` visible in the function also (i.e `int` or `float` in this case). The other types (allocator or `std::array` size) I dont care about.

What is the correct signature?

Comment: You won't be able to get one template to take them all as `std::array` uses a non type template parameter.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan - Answer improved: defining the type in `isCnt` with a name different by `type` (that is inherited also by `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`), say `containedType`, it's possible to simplify the SFINAE  enable/disable part working on `T` and avoiding the use of `std::enable_if` with the return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the correct signature?

As far I know, there isn't possible to write a single correct signature to intercept all containers and only containers.

But if you accept to write a type traits that say if a type is a container and extract the contained type (require a generic version, a partial specialization for `std::vector` and similar `typename ...` containers and a specialization for `std::array`; other specializations can be added) as the following `isCnt`

```
template <typename>
struct isCnt : public std::false_type
 { };

// std::array case
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C,
          typename T, std::size_t N >
struct isCnt<C<T, N>> : public std::true_type
 { using containedType = T; };

// other container case
template <template <typename ...> class C,
          typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct isCnt<C<T0, Ts...>> : public std::true_type
 { using containedType = T0; };
```

you can construct `setData()` as follows

template ::containedType>
   void SetData (C const & data)
    {
      // code here
    }

Observe that `setData()` is SFINAE enabled (or disabled) by `T = isCnt<C>::containedType`, that is available only for containers.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct isCnt : public std::false_type
 { };

// std::array case
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C,
          typename T, std::size_t N >
struct isCnt<C<T, N>> : public std::true_type
 { using containedType = T; };

// other container case
template <template <typename ...> class C,
          typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct isCnt<C<T0, Ts...>> : public std::true_type
 { using containedType = T0; };

struct Test
 {
   template <typename C, typename T = typename isCnt<C>::containedType>
   void SetData (C const & data)
    {
      if ( std::is_same<T, int>::value )
         std::cout << "- int case" << std::endl;
      else if ( std::is_same<T, float>::value )
         std::cout << "- float case" << std::endl;
    }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Test test;
   std::vector<int> vector{ 1,2,3 };
   std::array<float, 3> arr{ { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f } };

   test.SetData(vector); // print "int case"
   test.SetData(arr);    // print "float case"
   //test.SetData(0);    // compilation error
 }
```